# node.js ignores awaitZip building with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, async-await

I want to fetch icon PNGS from gridfs out of our mongodb database with mongoose. These icons then should be zipped and served at a specific route.

My current code is as follows:

```
var zip = require("node-native-zip");
async function getZipFile() {
    //get the events out of the DB
    db.Category.find({}).populate('icons.file').exec(async function (err, cats) {
        if (err) {
            //oh oh something went wrong, better pass the error along
            return ({
                    "success": "false",
                    message: err
                });
        }
        else {
            //all good, build the message and return
            try {
                const result = await buildZip(cats);
                return ({
                    "success": "true",
                    message: result
                });
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log("ZIP Build Failed")
            }
        }
    });
}
async function buildZip(cats) {
    let archive = new zip();
    for (let i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
        cats[i].icons.forEach(function (icon) {
            if (icon.size === "3x") {
                db.Attachment.readById(icon.file._id, function (err, buffer) {
                    if (err)
                        return;
                    archive.add(cats[i]._id + ".png", buffer);
                });
            }
        });
        //return when everything is done
        if (i === cats.length - 1) {
            return archive.toBuffer();
        }
    }
}
module.exports =
    {
        run: getZipFile
    };
```

I don't want to build the zip before runtime, as I want to rename the icons acording to the category ID. I tried going for a async/await structure, but my callback is being returned before the building of the zip file even started.

I'm calling the function with

```
    case 'categoryZip':
        categoryHelper.getZipFile.run().then((result) => {
            callback(result);
        });
        break;
```

This should (as far as I understood it) fire the callback when the zipping is done, but I think I'm missing something essential here.

Comment: callback-based APIs don't "just work" in `async` functions. You have to convert them to promises. The `async` functions here have no knowledge of the callbacks inside your `db` methods, and will not `await` them.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts so you are saying that i should convert `db.Category.find({}).populate('icons.file').exec` to a promised based function, await it and then go on with my async zip building?

Comment: Yes, that and `db.Attachment.readById()`, though that one probably won't work inside `forEach()`, you can use `for (const icon of cats[i].icons)` though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrapped both your callback methods into promises, and also awaited your double for-loop of callbacks in parallel using `Promise.all()` since they don't rely on each other and I assume they don't need to be in any particular order in the zip file:

```
async function getZipFile() {
  //get the events out of the DB
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.Category.find({}).populate('icons.file').exec(async function(err, cats) {
      if (err) {
        //oh oh something went wrong, better pass the error along
        reject({
          success: false,
          message: err
        });
      } else {
        //all good, build the message and return
        try {
          const result = await buildZip(cats);

          resolve({
            success: true,
            message: result
          });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("ZIP Build Failed")
          reject({
            success: false,
            message: err
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

async function buildZip(cats) {
  let archive = new zip();

  await Promise.all(
    cats.map(cat => Promise.all(cat.icons
      .filter(icon => icon.size === '3x')
      .map(icon => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.Attachment.readById(icon.file._id, function(err, buffer) {
          if (err) return reject(err);
          archive.add(cat._id + ".png", buffer);
          resolve();
        });
      }))
    ))
  );

  return archive.toBuffer()
}
```

Comment: Holy! Thanks alot, your answer and code works perfectly fine. This is totally amazing, never thought of that promise structure!

Comment: Glad I could help